# cannot account for all special characters in XML

Tags: xml, perl

I'm reading an XML file to remove duplicate songs in rhythmbox.

However, there are a lot of weird characters that I can find neither rhyme nor reason for in filenames.  They're not just escapes.

I'm using `XML::Hash` in Perl.

For example, I'm finding that

`%20` means a single whitespace.

`%5B` means `[`

and `%5D` means `]`

[What characters do I need to escape in XML documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents) and http://www.escapecodes.info/ are close to what I want, but didn't provide any useful information

I'm reading through https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Hash and I don't see any advice about these characters.

I could convert  every character back & forth, but there has to be a more elegant and readable way of doing this.  Google searches haven't turned up anything.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use diagnostics;
use feature 'say';
use autodie ':all';
use File::Slurp;
use XML::Hash;
use DDP;
use utf8::all;

my $xml_converter = XML::Hash -> new();
my $xml_data = read_file('/home/con/Downloads/rhythmdb.xml');
my $xml_hash = $xml_converter->fromXMLStringtoHash($xml_data);
#p $xml_hash->{rhythmdb}{entry}[0];
my %files_found;
my $new_hash;
my $new_index = 0;
foreach my $song_index (0..scalar @{ $xml_hash->{rhythmdb}{entry} } - 1 ) {
    my $file;
    if (defined $xml_hash->{rhythmdb}{entry}[$song_index]{location}{text}) {
        $file = $xml_hash->{rhythmdb}{entry}[$song_index]{location}{text}
    } else {
        say 'can\'t get file.';
        p $xml_hash->{rhythmdb}{entry}[$song_index];
        die
    }
    $file =~ s/^file:\/\///;
#   $file =~ s/%20/ /g;
#   $file =~ s/%5B/\[/g;
#   $file =~ s/%5D/\]/g;
    $new_hash->{rhythmdb}{entry}[$new_index] = $xml_hash->{rhythmdb}{entry}[$song_index];
    $new_index++;
}
```

is there a more elegant/idiomatic way of converting all of these mystery characters?

Comment: Use [URI::Escape](http://p3rl.org/URI::Escape) to decode the percent encoded characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be URL percent encoding[1].

If you know which fields will have the URL encoded you can simply use something to decode those "special characters" for example with uri_decode($encoded) from URI::Encode[2].

[1] https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

[2] https://metacpan.org/pod/URI::Encode